# How to execute query with IN clause in spring?

Tags: java, spring

I have following code :

```
try {
    MapSqlParameterSource parameters = new MapSqlParameterSource();
    parameters.addValue("ids", year);

    return this.template.getJdbcOperations().query(
            "SELECT * FROM INCOME WHERE PROVNUM=? AND FISCALDATE IN ( :ids )", this.rowMapper, parameters);   
} catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException ex) {
    return null;
}
```

But i am not able to send the value for PROVNUM. how to do that?

need help,
thanks.

Comment: The specific problem nothing to do with the IN clause.

Answer (score 9):

It looks like you are mixing named and position parameters. It's best to use one or the other, but not both.

Try

```
MapSqlParameterSource parameters = new MapSqlParameterSource();
parameters.addValue("ids", year);
 parameters.addValue("provnum", provnum);

return this.template.getJdbcOperations().query(
                    "SELECT * FROM INCOME WHERE PROVNUM=:provnum AND FISCALDATE IN ( :ids )", this.rowMapper, parameters);
```

After your comment, I see that you are using the wrong overload of the `query()` method: there are quite a few to choose from, so it's not surprising a few errors can creep in!

You need to call

```
return this.template.getJdbcOperations().query(
       "SELECT  ... etc.", parameters, this.rowMapper);
```

In your original call, you are calling the version `query(String sql, RowMapper mapper, Object... params)` that expects literal parameters. The revised call is query(String sql, SqlParameterSource params, RowMapper mapper) - the SqlParamtersSource as the second argument is the key. Also, just worth checking that that you are using [NamedParameterJdbcTemplate](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/).

Comment: I think that's the key, make sure what you are using is the NamedParameterJdbcTemplate, the regular JdbcTemplate doesn't support the named parameters.

Answer (score 4):

Just use a named parameter for "provnum" also:

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM INCOME WHERE PROVNUM=:provnum AND FISCALDATE IN (:ids )"
MapSqlParameterSource parameters = new MapSqlParameterSource();
parameters.addValue("ids", year);
parameters.addValue("provnum", ...);
return template.getJdbcOperations().query(sql, rowMapper, parameters);
```

Comment: getting this execption org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [SELECT * FROM INCOME WHERE PROVNUM=:provNum AND FISCALDATE IN ( :ids )]; Unable to convert between org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.MapSqlParameterSource and JAVA_OBJECT.; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Unable to convert between org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.MapSqlParameterSource and JAVA_OBJECT.

Comment: The SpringSource documentation on this can be found: 
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/jdbc.html#jdbc-in-clause

Make sure that you are using a collection implementing the List interface and that you are not using a custom object. To be truthful, I haven't tried this with a list of Dates, but Matt's example would work for List<Integer>, List<Long> etc.

Comment: @GK please post the code in question, including the types/values of whatever parameters you add with `addValue()`