# Safely prepare comma delimited list for query

Tags: java, spring, jdbc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to generate a dynamic “in (…)” sql list through Spring JdbcTemplate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981683/how-to-generate-a-dynamic-in-sql-list-through-spring-jdbctemplate)

I'm trying to prepare a list of IDs for a `IN()` clause in MsSQL in java.  I've got the below code which looks like it should work, but it's throwing the error: java.sql.SQLException: Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '1,2' to data type int.

I'm kind of at a total loss as to why it's trying it like an integer when I'm passing a string.  Any insight would be great.

I've also tried changing `template.getId()` to `template.getId().toString()` with no luck

```
    //JOINs
    Collection<Template> templates = search.getTemplateCollection();
    if (templates != null && templates.size() > 0) {
        searchQuery.append("INNER JOIN dbo.content_to_template ON content_to_template.template_id IN (:templateIds) AND content_to_template.content_id = content.id ");

        StringBuilder templateIds = new StringBuilder();
        for (Template template : templates) {
            if (templateIds.length() == 0) {
                templateIds.append(template.getId());
            } else {
                templateIds.append(",").append(template.getId());
            }
        }
        queryMap.put("templateIds", templateIds.toString());
    }



return this.namedjdbcTemplate.query(searchQuery.toString(), new MapSqlParameterSource(queryMap), this.contentRowMapper);
```

Comment: Shouldn't `templateIds` be a collection of ints rather than a string? Your solution wouldn't be very safe even if the string solution worked, as any commas in `template.getId()` will introduce spurious values.

Comment: Yeah, as @biziclop mentioned - try using int[] as a parameter, if it is possible ofcourse.

Comment: Take a look at this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2810418/how-to-execute-query-with-in-clause-in-spring

Comment: Or this one [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981683/how-to-generate-a-dynamic-in-sql-list-through-spring-jdbctemplate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981683/how-to-generate-a-dynamic-in-sql-list-through-spring-jdbctemplate)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to prepare a collection of template IDs and pass it to the map.
String delimited data may not work as it expects a collection.

=======================

```
List templateIds = new ArrayList(); 
templateIds.add(template.getId()); 

----
---

 queryMap.put("templateIds", templateIds);
```